# Apache Drill 1.17.0 on Windows 10 - Trouble Getting Drill to Run (Embedded Mode)

Tags: apache-drill

Details:

- Apache Drill 1.17.0
- Windows 10 64 bit
- Java JDK1.8.0_241

New installation.  Unable to get Apache Drill to load successfully.

Command line:  c:\Users\floodb\Software\Drill\apache-drill-1.17.0\bin>drill-embedded

**Error Received**:  *Error: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit: UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION ERROR: Failure while attempting to load instance of the class of type org.apache.drill.exec.store.StoragePluginRegistry requested at path drill.exec.storage.registry.*

*[Error Id: 7c1b33eb-7a27-4e39-af06-5ba22e5ffae6 ] (state=,code=0)
java.sql.SQLException: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit: UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION ERROR: Failure while attempting to load instance of the class of type org.apache.drill.exec.store.StoragePluginRegistry requested at path drill.exec.storage.registry.*

There is no 'hadoop_home' environment variable set (as suggested by other posts on StackOverflow).

Partial Log:

> 2020-02-19 15:55:42,315 [main] INFO 
>   o.a.drill.common.util.GuavaPatcher - Google's Stopwatch patched for
>   old HBase Guava version. 2020-02-19 15:55:42,319 [main] INFO 
>   o.a.drill.common.util.GuavaPatcher - Google's Closeables patched for
>   old HBase Guava version. 2020-02-19 15:55:42,333 [main] INFO 
>   o.a.drill.common.util.GuavaPatcher - Google's Preconditions were
>   patched to hold new methods. 2020-02-19 15:55:42,693 [main] INFO 
>   o.a.drill.common.config.DrillConfig - Configuration and plugin file(s)
>   identified in 32ms. Base Configuration:
>     - jar:file:/C:/Users/floodb/Software/Drill/apache-drill-1.17.0/jars/drill-common-1.17.0.jar!/drill-default.conf
>
> (Bunch of log lines deleted)
>
> 2020-02-19 15:55:45,134 [main] INFO  o.a.d.c.s.persistence.ScanResult
>   - loading 22 classes for org.apache.drill.common.logical.data.LogicalOperator took 4ms
>   2020-02-19 15:55:45,138 [main] INFO  o.a.d.c.s.persistence.ScanResult
>   - loading 12 classes for org.apache.drill.common.logical.StoragePluginConfig took 3ms
>   2020-02-19 15:55:45,146 [main] INFO  o.a.d.c.s.persistence.ScanResult
>   - loading 15 classes for org.apache.drill.common.logical.FormatPluginConfig took 7ms 2020-02-19
>   15:55:45,179 [main] INFO  o.a.drill.common.config.DrillConfig - User
>   Error Occurred: Failure while attempting to load instance of the class
>   of type org.apache.drill.exec.store.StoragePluginRegistry requested at
>   path drill.exec.storage.registry. (null)
>   org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserException:
>   UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION ERROR: Failure while attempting to load instance
>   of the class of type org.apache.drill.exec.store.StoragePluginRegistry
>   requested at path drill.exec.storage.registry.
>
> [Error Id: 7c1b33eb-7a27-4e39-af06-5ba22e5ffae6 ]     at
>   org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserException$Builder.build(UserException.java:637)
>     at
>   org.apache.drill.common.config.DrillConfig.getInstance(DrillConfig.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.drill.exec.server.DrillbitContext.(DrillbitContext.java:113)
>     at org.apache.drill.exec.work.WorkManager.start(WorkManager.java:116)
>     at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.run(Drillbit.java:221)     at
>   org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.(DrillConnectionImpl.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.calcite.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:138)
>     at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:75)     at
>   sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:135)   at
>   sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:192)
>     at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1364)     at
>   sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1244)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sqlline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:38)
>     at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:730)   at
>   sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:410)    at
>   sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:515)   at
>   sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:267)   at
>   sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:206) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.drill.common.config.DrillConfig.getInstance(DrillConfig.java:88)
>     ... 22 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
>     at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1435)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:493)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1868)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1910)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:678)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1868)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1910)
>     at
>   org.apache.drill.exec.store.dfs.DrillFileSystem.listStatus(DrillFileSystem.java:563)
>     at
>   org.apache.drill.exec.util.FileSystemUtil.listNonRecursive(FileSystemUtil.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.drill.exec.util.FileSystemUtil.list(FileSystemUtil.java:209)
>     at
>   org.apache.drill.exec.util.FileSystemUtil.listFiles(FileSystemUtil.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.drill.exec.util.DrillFileSystemUtil.listFiles(DrillFileSystemUtil.java:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.drill.exec.store.sys.store.LocalPersistentStore.getRange(LocalPersistentStore.java:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.drill.exec.store.sys.BasePersistentStore.getAll(BasePersistentStore.java:27)
>     at
>   org.apache.drill.exec.store.StoragePluginRegistryImpl.initPluginsSystemTable(StoragePluginRegistryImpl.java:277)
>     at
>   org.apache.drill.exec.store.StoragePluginRegistryImpl.(StoragePluginRegistryImpl.java:90)
>     ... 27 common frames omitted 2020-02-19 15:55:46,199 [main] INFO 
>   o.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit - Shutdown completed (1018 ms).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the 32 bit version of the Java JDK was installed.  If you are having this problem, check to make sure that the 64 bit version of Java is installed.