# Apache Drill failing to launch

Tags: java, apache-drill

I am facing an issue while executing apache-drill sqlline.bat

```
sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local"
```

could you please suggest the fix for this.

Setup:

- Windows11 64-bit,
- Java 1.8.0_202 64 bit,
- Apache Drill 1.17.0

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a duplicate of this issue:
[Apache Drill 1.17.0 on Windows 10 - Trouble Getting Drill to Run (Embedded Mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60310197/apache-drill-1-17-0-on-windows-10-trouble-getting-drill-to-run-embedded-mode)

Really however, I would strongly recommend that you upgrade your Drill to the most current version.  Drill 1.17.0 is several years old at this point and there have been many bug fixes and enhancements since then.

Comment: I have tried this but still, the same error getting.

Comment: found fix thank you so much @James Turton <dzamo@apache.org>                                                                                 
                Fix is:   >set HADOOP_HOME=
                           >drill-embedded.bat OR >sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local"